# I am trying to run a query using multiple tables where i want to fetch single row of consumers with there maximum read date and last register reading

Tags: sql

I am trying to run the following query

```
SELECT
    a.REG_CONSUMER_NAME, a.CUSTOMER_ID,
    a.FEEDER_CODE, a.FEEDER_NAME,
    a.DT_CODE, a.DT_NAME, a.SERIAL_NBR,
    b.METER_READER_NAME,
    a.Rs_CD, a.INSTALLATION_NUMBER, 
    MAX(d.end_read_dttm)
FROM
    xx_consumer_det_mvw a, xx_meter_reader_rt b, ci_bseg c, ci_bseg_read d 
WHERE
    a.dt_code = b.dt_code 
    AND a.sa_id = c.sa_id 
    AND c.bseg_id = d.bseg_id  
    AND customer_id = '0204040003214'
GROUP BY
    a.REG_CONSUMER_NAME, a.CUSTOMER_ID, a.FEEDER_CODE, a.DT_CODE,         
    a.FEEDER_NAME, a.DT_CODE, a.DT_NAME, a.SERIAL_NBR,
    b.METER_READER_NAME, a.Rs_CD, a.INSTALLATION_NUMBER, d.END_REG_READING;
```

This is the output I am getting:

[image]

This is the output I want to get:

[image]

Please note this is only one consumer for reference as I am trying to run query for fetching data for multiple consumers.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: It's probably a mistake in the `GROUP BY` terms.  Without having the exact data, it's tough to identify the precise issue / logic that needs to be corrected. Please provide a runnable, working test case that produces the behavior of interest.  That should include the `CREATE TABLE`, and `INSERT` statements, plus the database you're using (oracle, MySQL, PG, etc) and the exact version you're using.

Comment: Try removing `d.END_REG_READING` from the `GROUP BY` terms.  That appears to be the issue.

Comment: Thankyou @JonArmstrong removing d.END_REG_READING worked.